# Python Mock class import error

Tags: python, elasticsearch, mocking

I'm trying to mock **elasticsearch.Elasticsearch.indices.exists** function in my Python test case, but I'm getting the following import error. However, mock just **elasticsearch.Elasticsearch** was working fine.

```
@ddt
class TestElasticSearchConnector(unittest.TestCase):

    @patch('elasticsearch.Elasticsearch.indices.exists')
    @patch('connectors.elastic_search_connector.ElasticSearchConnector._get_local_conn')
    def test_check_index(self, mock_es, _get_local_conn):
        mock_es = Mock()
        mock_es._index_exists = False
        mock_es.indices.exists.return_value = True
        mock_es.create.return_value = {'result': 'created'}
```

Getting the mock import error here

======================================================================
    ERROR: test_check_index (tests.base.TestESConnector)
    ----------------------------------------------------------------------
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/Users/user/.virtualenvs/my-prjlib/python3.6/site-packages/mock/mock.py", line 1197, in _dot_lookup
        return getattr(thing, comp)
    AttributeError: type object 'Elasticsearch' has no attribute 'indices'

```
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/user/.virtualenvs/my-prjlib/python3.6/site-packages/mock/mock.py", line 1297, in patched
    arg = patching.__enter__()
  File "/Users/user/.virtualenvs/my-prjlib/python3.6/site-packages/mock/mock.py", line 1353, in __enter__
    self.target = self.getter()
  File "/Users/user/.virtualenvs/my-prjlib/python3.6/site-packages/mock/mock.py", line 1523, in <lambda>
    getter = lambda: _importer(target)
  File "/Users/user/.virtualenvs/my-prjlib/python3.6/site-packages/mock/mock.py", line 1210, in _importer
    thing = _dot_lookup(thing, comp, import_path)
  File "/Users/user/.virtualenvs/my-prjlib/python3.6/site-packages/mock/mock.py", line 1199, in _dot_lookup
    __import__(import_path)
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'elasticsearch.Elasticsearch'

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.001s

FAILED (errors=1)
```

Test import

```
>>  user$ python
Python 3.6.1 (default, May 10 2017, 09:46:05) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 8.1.0 (clang-802.0.42)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch
>>> 
>>>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is legitimately an error. When specifying an attribute/method to mock, it must exist on the object (in this case a class). Perhaps you were expecting this attribute to exist, but it only present on the instantiated object.

```
In [1]: from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch
In [2]: Elasticsearch.indices
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-313eaaedb2f6> in <module>()
----> 1 Elasticsearch.indices
```

Indeed, it exists on an instantiated object:

```
In [3]: Elasticsearch().indices
Out[3]: <elasticsearch.client.indices.IndicesClient at 0x102db0a90>
```

Answer (score 0):

The Elasticserch library generates the `indices` attribute when you instantiante an `Elasticsearch()` object. And it does so using a class of the library called `IndicesClient`, and it is that class who has the `exists` method. Therefore, if you mock the response of that method of the `IndicesClient` class, you test should work.

Also, the input params of the function should be in reverse order with respoect of the decorators. If you put the `indices.exists` patch first, that should go second in the input to the function.

```
from elasticsearch.client import IndicesClient

@mock.patch.object(IndicesClient, 'exists')
@mock.patch('connectors.elastic_search_connector.ElasticSearchConnector._get_local_conn')
def test_check_index(self, mock_get_local_conn, mock_exists):
    mock_exists.return_value = True
    ...
```